# Magento 2.2.4 - Unable to overwrite Core Module Translations files

Tags: magento2, localisation

Here, I want to overwrite below **csv** file using the custom theme

**(without creating separate modules)**

It's should not take data from core **CSV** file.

```
vendor/amzn/amazon-pay-and-login-magento-2-module/src/Core/i18n/en_US.csv
```

Core Translations

> "Back","Back to register or connect an account"

Need To Overwrite

> "Back", "Back"

Comment: This is default magento issue and it's resolved : https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/14978

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to using
cweagans/composer-patches to patch composer module

Referrer link [here](https://support.magento.com/hc/en-us/articles/360005484154-Create-a-patch-for-a-Magento-2-Composer-installation-from-a-GitHub-commit)

The extension was upgraded also removed references to 'Back', try to upgrade to latest version

[Pull request](https://github.com/amzn/amazon-payments-magento-2-plugin/pull/252)

Answer (score 0):

This is default magento issue, For temporary, we change "**Back**","**Back to register or connect an account**" To "**Back**","**Back**" in below file then it will work

> vendor/amzn/amazon-pay-and-login-magento-2-module/src/Core/i18n/en_GB.csv:79
>   vendor/amzn/amazon-pay-and-login-magento-2-module/src/Core/i18n/en_US.csv:79

**Then run below command.**

> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

For more information [github.com/magento/magento2/issues](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/15024)